# pysvn.Client.callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt error

Tags: python, pysvn

I am getting the `pysvn.Client.callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt required` error when trying to commit.  I understand it has to do with trust with the internet validation.

Here is the documentation, I just don't understand it.

```
pysvn.Client.callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt

import pysvn

def ssl_server_trust_prompt( trust_dict ):
    return retcode, accepted_failures, save

client = pysvn.Client()
client.callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt = ssl_server_trust_prompt
```

> The callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt
> is called each time an HTTPS server
> presents a certificate and subversion
> is not sure if it should be trusted.
> callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt is
> called with information about the
> certificate in trust dict.
>
> failures - int - a bitmask of failures
>
> - [What do these bits mean?] hostname - string - the hostname the certificate was presented from
>   finger_print - string - certificate
>   finger print valid_from - string -
>   valid from this ISO8601 date
>   valid_until - string - valid util this
>   ISO8601 date issuer_dname - stirng -
>   the issued dname realm - string - the
>   realm pysvn expect the
>   callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt to
>   return a tuple of three values
>   (retcode, accepted_failures, save).
>
> retcode - boolean, False if no
> username and password are available.
> True if subversion is to use the
> username and password.
> accepted_failures - int, the accepted
> failures allowed save - boolean,
> return True if you want subversion to
> remember the certificate in the
> configuration directory. return False
> to prevent saving the certificate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When pysvn attempts to perform operations on a repository that you access using https, it needs to validate the servers identity.  This is done by calling a function called callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt.  By default this function is not defined.  You, as the programmer, must supply the trust information, which you do by writing a function that looks at the information in the trust dictionary, and returns a tuple of 3 values (described in the third paragraph of the documentation).

Once you have written the function, you make it the callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt by assigning your function name to client.callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt

Comment: What information should this "trust dictionary" precisely contain? How should it be structured? What are the key/value pairs?

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed an error in the docs that may have mislead about the meaning of retcode. The updated docs are live at:

http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt

The values in trust_dict are all documented.

Typically you will prompt a human to decide if the server certificate is to be trusted.

But here is the simplest function that will always accept a server certificate.

```
def ssl_server_trust_prompt( trust_dict ):
    return (True    # server is trusted
           ,trust_dict["failures"]
           ,True)   # save the answer so that the callback is not called again
```

Barry Scott author of pysvn.

Comment: Isn't it unsafe to accept all certificates? This makes the certificate check effectively moot, and allows easy MitM attacks.

Comment: Alright. Do you know of a way to ask the operating system? If the certificate is signed by a root CA or one of its descendants, that should suffice.

Comment: The subversion developers are the people you need to check with but I think that svn did the trust checks before poping this callback. I think this means that as far as svn and the installed root certs are concerned this cert is not trusted.

Comment: The certs that are checked are the ones that OpenSSL is configured with. THis turns out to be the ones that the OS is configured with apparently. Therefore if you see this callback it means that we are missing the CA cert need to authentice this cert.

Comment: As I'm on Windows, it might also be the case that OpenSSL is not installed at all (I don't think it is).

Comment: pysvn installs OpenSSL as part of the DLLs needed to allow SVN to use https:. On windows the credential store should be used to hold the passwords.