# pysvn checkout error ""Server SSL certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted". on proxy server

Tags: pysvn

I'm trying to do SVN checkout using `pysvn`, but facing the error:

> Server SSL certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted

We are using a proxy URL to checkout. Manual checkout and `svn` command line checkout work fine on this URL.

Please suggest any solution how to checkout proxy SVN URL using `pysvn`.

```
client = pysvn.Client()
client.callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt = ssl_server_trust_prompt
client.callback_get_login = get_login
client.checkout(<URL>, <PATH>, recurse=True)
```

Comment: Check out Barry Scott's answer here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893218/pysvn-client-callback-ssl-server-trust-prompt-error